# Trouble finding / building WebRTC targets in Chrome source

Tags: google-chrome, cmake, build, webrtc, chromium

I am building chrome m99 milestone and cannot seem to find where it builds the webrtc library which it uses.  when you goto webrtc.org its all chrome javascript examples of its usage case, but in reality native servers must stream this to make real use of it for low latency apps. certainly we arent packaging chrome apps on the server for this purpose, nor would it be possible to actually access video buffers efficiently using that.

i've attempted to build with targets webrtc, //gen/third_party/webrtc, i've attempted to gen directly in the webrtc dir (in third_party) which has a BUILD.gn, but you cannot.  it errors and says there are missing build files:

```
C:\src\chromium\src\third_party\webrtc>gn gen out/Debug
ERROR at //.gn:9:1: Unable to load "C:/src/chromium/src/third_party/webrtc/build/dotfile_settings.gni".
import("//build/dotfile_settings.gni")
```

I see in its BUILD.gn it has a 'build_with_chromium' boolean but does not seem any way to do that.  the last doc i saw on this was from 2017 in a blog post, and the libwebrtc project he used is no longer maintained.  the guy went commercial but essentially it gloms together a bunch of .o's into a lib but none of the third party structure is the same anymore in m99.

inside chromium checkout:

```
# fetch branch head info so that we can checkout m99
# https://chromiumdash.appspot.com/branches (4844 branch ref = m99)
gclient sync --with_branch_heads --with_tags
git fetch
git checkout -b branch_4844 branch-heads/4844 
gclient sync --with_branch_heads --with_tags

# use depot_tools of our own (in PATH)
set DEPOT_TOOLS_WIN_TOOLCHAIN=0

# is_component_build=true disables webrtc as i'm noticing in the main build in chrome, so i set it to false to be sure (i believe its false by default)

gn gen out/Default --args="is_component_build=false symbol_level=0 is_debug=true"

autoninja -C out/Default chrome
```

since chrome uses webrtc it should be built, but who knows where the objs are?

in libwebrtc (no longer maintained) circa m62 or so they selected these binaries for producing a lib:

```
file(GLOB_RECURSE _OBJ_EXCLUDED
     ${WEBRTC_OUTPUT_DIR}/obj/third_party/yasm/gen*/*${_OBJ_EXT}
     ${WEBRTC_OUTPUT_DIR}/obj/third_party/yasm/re2c/*${_OBJ_EXT}
     ${WEBRTC_OUTPUT_DIR}/obj/third_party/yasm/yasm/*${_OBJ_EXT}
     ${WEBRTC_OUTPUT_DIR}/obj/third_party/protobuf/protoc/*${_OBJ_EXT}
     ${WEBRTC_OUTPUT_DIR}/obj/third_party/protobuf/protobuf_full/*${_OBJ_EXT}
     ${WEBRTC_OUTPUT_DIR}/obj/webrtc/examples/*${_OBJ_EXT}
     ${WEBRTC_OUTPUT_DIR}/obj/webrtc/tools/*${_OBJ_EXT}
     ${WEBRTC_OUTPUT_DIR}/obj/webrtc/modules/video_capture/video_capture/video_capture_external${_OBJ_EXT}
     ${WEBRTC_OUTPUT_DIR}/obj/webrtc/modules/video_capture/video_capture/device_info_external${_OBJ_EXT})
```

it was made at a time where webrtc could be built on its own, but it just does not seem to be the case anymore unless there is a magical '1-2-3' that could build the hard work of these great
people who seem to not want to expose a library?

I've attempted to give it webrtc, /third_party/webrtc, //gen/third_party/webrtc.  no avail it is just completely inaccessible as-is.

openwebrtc is not maintained, nor is libwebrtc which glommed this all together.

Comment: building from inside a chrome checkout instead of following the normal instructions from  https://webrtc.googlesource.com/src/+/main/docs/native-code/development/index.md is unusual. Any reason you are attempting to do this?
Most likely you are not running a gclient sync inside that directory which means the dependencies (like the build directory) are not installed.